# Access JSON Values in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

Using an obscure fork of an ancient gem, I finally figured out how to access the Zillow API for my Rails app and now have the following hash, generated by `result.to_hash`:

> {"xmlns:UpdatedPropertyDetails"=>"http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/UpdatedPropertyDetails.xsd",
>   "xsi:schemaLocation"=>"http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/UpdatedPropertyDetails.xsd
>   http://www.zillowstatic.com/vstatic/3af70b5/static/xsd/UpdatedPropertyDetails.xsd",
>   "xmlns:xsi"=>"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
>   "request"=>[{"zpid"=>["51654945"]}], "message"=>[{"text"=>["Request
>   successfully processed"], "code"=>["0"]}],
>   "response"=>[{"zpid"=>["51654945"],
>   "pageViewCount"=>[{"currentMonth"=>["3977"], "total"=>["3977"]}],
>   "address"=>[{"street"=>["10 Oak View Dr"], "zipcode"=>["92656"],
>   "city"=>["Aliso Viejo"], "state"=>["CA"], "latitude"=>["33.57314"],
>   "longitude"=>["-117.739995"]}],
>   "links"=>[{"homeDetails"=>["http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/10-Oak-View-Dr-Aliso-Viejo-CA-92656/51654945_zpid/"],
>   "photoGallery"=>["http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/10-Oak-View-Dr-Aliso-Viejo-CA-92656/51654945_zpid/#image=lightbox%3Dtrue"],
>   "homeInfo"=>["http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/10-Oak-View-Dr-Aliso-Viejo-CA-92656/51654945_zpid/"]}],
>   "images"=>[{"count"=>["10"],
>   "image"=>[{"url"=>["https://photos.zillowstatic.com/p_d/ISz0br27tav6w3.jpg",
>   "https://photos.zillowstatic.com/p_d/ISz2d9cyty5ig3.jpg",
>   "https://photos.zillowstatic.com/p_d/ISz0br5ab169ib.jpg",
>   "https://photos.zillowstatic.com/p_d/ISz0br5i75mher.jpg",
>   "https://photos.zillowstatic.com/p_d/ISz0br52ewq1lv.jpg"]}]}],
>   "editedFacts"=>[{"useCode"=>["SingleFamily"], "bedrooms"=>["5"],
>   "bathrooms"=>["3.0"], "finishedSqFt"=>["3700"],
>   "lotSizeSqFt"=>["7599"], "yearBuilt"=>["2000"], "numFloors"=>["2"],
>   "basement"=>["None"], "roof"=>["Tile"],
>   "exteriorMaterial"=>["Stucco"], "view"=>["Mountain"],
>   "parkingType"=>["Garage - Attached, Off-street"],
>   "coveredParkingSpaces"=>["3"], "heatingSources"=>["Solar"],
>   "heatingSystem"=>["Forced air"], "coolingSystem"=>["Central"],
>   "appliances"=>["Dishwasher, Dryer, Freezer, Garbage disposal,
>   Microwave, Range / Oven, Refrigerator"], "floorCovering"=>["Carpet,
>   Hardwood, Tile, Other"], "rooms"=>["Dining room, Family room, Laundry
>   room, Master bath, Office, Walk-in closet"], "architecture"=>["Cape
>   Cod"]}], "homeDescription"=>["Beautiful, 5 bedroom executive home with
>   bonus room and 3.5 bathrooms located in the popular Kensington
>   neighborhood. 3,700 sq. ft. (n/t) of living space. Large gourmet
>   upgraded kitchen with chef’s prep island. Huge family room with
>   fireplace, formal dining and living rooms with hardwood floors
>   throughout. Upgraded lighting, arched entries, California shutters.
>   Oversized, private backyard with mature landscaping and great side
>   patio for a bar and BBQ. Enjoy the pristine swimming pool and spa with
>   rock water slide. Sitting area with fire pit for cozy evenings and
>   endless panoramic views. To view this spectacular home call Blair at
>   (949) 433-5203.\n\n\nNeighborhood Description\n\nBest city to work and
>   live in ! Blue ribbon award winning schools!"],
>   "whatOwnerLoves"=>["The Custom pool, spa & rock water slide!"],
>   "schoolDistrict"=>["Capistrano Unified"]}]}

I am now trying to access the image urls (or more realistically the first of the image URL array), but I can't seem to take the last step.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
result.to_hash['response'].first['images'].first['image'].first['url'].first
```

Comment: Sweet baby Jesus, it works!  Thank you!  Why are there so many `first`s, just for learning purposes?

Comment: Most of the keys are arrays and you are accessing the first element of the array. So you need to use first so many times. Accept the answer if this was what you where looking for :)

Comment: Yes, that's awesome.  Thank you!